# Calculation complexity of boolean function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have boolean function of next variables: $x_{ij}$, $ 1 \leq i \leq n$ and $1 \leq j \leq m$. And the function is equal to 1 only when we have such $i$ that $x_{ij} = 1$ for any j. Can I calculate the value of the function in less than $n*m$ questions ($x_{ij} = 0?$)?